# Express res.write() not working as expected when switched from http to https

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https

I am using express.write() method to stream links that are gathered through a recursive script. It is working fine locally and on an nginx server without the SSL. However, when I added SSL response is not streamed rather is returned when the script is finished. Here's the controller

```
const getLinks = async (req, response) => {
  response.flush = () => {};
  if (!req.query.siteUrl) {
    return res.json({ error: "Site url not provided" });
  }

  response.writeHead(206, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  });

  const crawl = async (url) => {
    totalUrlsVisited++;
    // console.log(`Crawling: ${url}`);
    const links = await getAllWebsiteLinks(url, internalUrls);
    if (links.length) {
      for (const link of links) {
        if (totalUrlsVisited < 30) await crawl(link);
      }
    }
  };

  const isValid = (url) => {
    if (url.includes("@")) return false;
    if (url.includes("mailto")) return false;
    const parsedUrl = urlparse.parse(url);
    const result = Boolean(parsedUrl.hostname) && Boolean(parsedUrl.protocol);

    return result;
  };

  const getAllWebsiteLinks = async (url, internalUrls) => {
    const urls = [];
    let res;
    try {
      res = await axios.get(url, { timeout: "10000" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message, url);
      return [];
    }
    const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
    const allATags = $("a").toArray();

    for (const element of allATags) {
      const $element = $(element);
      let href = $element.attr("href");
      if (!href || href === "") continue;
      const absoluteUrl = new URL(href, url).toString();
      const parsedUrl = urlparse.parse(absoluteUrl);
      const sanitizedUrl = `${parsedUrl.protocol}//${parsedUrl.hostname}${
        parsedUrl.pathname ? parsedUrl.pathname : ""
      }`;
      if (internalUrls.includes(sanitizedUrl)) continue;
      if (parsedUrl.hostname !== domainName) continue;
      if (!isValid(sanitizedUrl)) continue;
      internalUrls.push(sanitizedUrl);
      urls.push(sanitizedUrl);
      urlsBatch.push(sanitizedUrl);
      if (urlsBatch.length === 5) {
        await response.write(JSON.stringify(urlsBatch));

        console.log(urlsBatch);
        urlsBatch = [];
      }
    }

    return urls;
  };

  const internalUrls = [];
  let totalUrlsVisited = 0;
  let urlsBatch = [];
  const url = req.query.siteUrl;
  const domainName = urlparse.parse(url).hostname;

  await crawl(url, internalUrls, totalUrlsVisited);
  console.log(internalUrls.length, totalUrlsVisited);
  response.end();
};
```

On the client I am reading the response as follows:

```
 try {
      setFetchingMore(true);
      const { auth } = await chrome.storage.local.get("auth");
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/chat/get_links/?siteUrl=${window.location.origin}`,
        {
          signal: controller.signal,
          headers: {
            Accept: "text/event-stream",
            Authorization: auth.id_token,
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }

      for (const reader = response.body.getReader(); ; ) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();

        if (done) {
          setFetchingMore(false);
          break;
        }

        const chunk = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
        console.log(chunk);
        // console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
        // setLinks((curr) => [...curr, ...JSON.parse(chunk)]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Here's my nginx configuration

```
server {
    if ($host = api.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


                listen 80;
                server_name api.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need some specific configuration in nginx so that nginx will stream to your host rather than wait for the connection to complete before sending the request through.

Comment: @jfriend00 I suspect the same, but not really sure what would work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off proxy buffering in the nginx config solves the issue

`proxy_buffering off;`

Comment: I see you found it.  Cool.